# How to output lines longer than a specified number of words in Bash using awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep

I want to output lines that are longer than a specified number of words, let say 5. I used `awk` as below, but it did not work for files containing very long sentences (exceeding 32767 fields).

```
awk 'NF>5' FS=" " file.txt
```

I tried using `sed` and `grep` as recommended in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726240/how-do-i-remove-all-lines-in-a-file-that-are-less-than-6-characters) but I could not make it work based on the number of words, not characters.

Could you please help me on this problem? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean saying without GNU awk? Do you have any other variants of awk installed in your system?

Comment: Try to phrase your requirements in a positive instead of negative way, it'll make them much easier to understand and so the resulting code more likely to be correct. Instead of `I want to remove lines that are shorter than a specified number of words, lets say 5` simply say `I want to output lines that are longer than a specified number of words, lets say 4`. By talking about what you want to output rather than what you want to remove from the output, your needs and limit become much clearer.

Comment: Also - installing gawk is one potential solution to your problem but it's not your problem so it shouldn't be such a big part oof your question. your REAL question should be "how do I do X when I only have Y awk available on system Z". You MAY have a different awk than the one you're using already available on your system (e.g. Solaris has 3 awk variants) but you haven't told us anything about the awk you're using or the system you're on, just that you can't install gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh, I just read your comments now. Thank you so much for your valuable advice! I'll edit my question and pay attention to make my future questions clearer and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep '\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\|$\)\)\{5,\}' file
```

Or if your grep has `-E`:

```
grep -E '([^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+|$)){5,}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}[^[:space:]]/' file
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as well and is a little faster than the solution using `grep`. I accepted previous solution so I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @oguzismail I think it's okay. The time difference is insignificant. You answered very quickly right after I posted the question and that saved me a lot of time getting stuck at one point. Thank you very much once again! :)